# Anime App API Response Doesn't Match Room Database Data! jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
//Remote mediator

@ExperimentalPagingApi
class AnimeRemoteMediator @Inject constructor(
    val AnimeDb: AnimeDatabase,
    val jikanApi: jikanApi
):RemoteMediator<Int, AnimeEntity>() {
   override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, AnimeEntity>,
    ): MediatorResult {
       return try {

           val loadkey = when(loadType){
               LoadType.REFRESH ->1
               LoadType.PREPEND -> return MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = false)
               LoadType.APPEND -> {
          val pageNo = Constants.name.toInt()
                   pageNo+1
               }
           }
Log.d("mrm","loadkey is:${loadkey}")

           delay(2000L)
           val anime = jikanApi.getAnimeList(
               currentPage = loadkey,
               pageSize = state.config.pageSize,
               orderBy = "popularity"
           )


Constants.name = anime.pagination.currentPage.toString()
           val animeEntity:List<AnimeEntity> = anime.data.map {
               if(it.studios.isEmpty()){
                   it.studios = listOf(
                       Studio(1,"Unknown","unknown","unknown")
                   )
               }

             if(it.score==null){
                   it.score=10.0
               }
                if(it.scoredBy==0){
                   it.scoredBy=10
               }
               if(it.rank==null){
                   it.rank=10
               }
               if(it.synopsis==null){
                   it.synopsis="Currently not available"
               }
            it.toAnimeEntity()
           }
Log.d("mrm","animeEntity: ${animeEntity.map { it.name}}")
           delay(1000L)
              AnimeDb.dao.upsertAll(animeEntity)

            MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached = !anime.pagination.hasNextPage)
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            MediatorResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

```
//AnimeEntity

@Entity(tableName = "animeList")
data class AnimeEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id:Int,
    val name:String
    ,val imageUrl:String?
    ,val totalEpisodes:Int?,
    val aired:String?,
    val status:String?,
    val rating:String?,
    val score:Double?,
    val scoredBy:Int?,
    val synopsis:String?,
    var studio: String?,
  val genres:List<String>?
)
```

```
//Api request
{https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime?order_by=popularity&page=1&limit=20}
```

```
//logcat of response I am getting from api into database

animeEntity: [Meitantei Pikachu: Kareinaru Morning Routine, Shingeki no Kyojin, Death Note, Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood, One Punch Man, Sword Art Online, Boku no Hero Academia, Kimetsu no Yaiba, Naruto, Tokyo Ghoul, Hunter x Hunter (2011), Kimi no Na wa., Shingeki no Kyojin Season 2, Steins;Gate, Boku no Hero Academia 2nd Season, Naruto: Shippuuden, Jujutsu Kaisen, No Game No Life, Shingeki no Kyojin Season 3, One Piece]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfaDj.png)

> I am currently working on an anime app where I retrieve data from an API to display a list of anime along with their detailed information. However, I am encountering a perplexing issue. The response I receive from the API seems to differ from the data that is getting stored in my Room database. Despite logging the API response and cross-verifying the data, I am unable to identify the root cause of this inconsistency.

To give you a clear picture of my problem, I have provided the relevant code snippets and the log cat displaying the API response. Additionally, I have included an image showcasing the data that is getting stored in the Room database. I have thoroughly checked my code for any discrepancies but haven't been able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I will ask you does the animes your getting from the api have there own Id and you're using that id as the primary key for your `AnimeEntity` in room database?

Comment: yes i am using it as my primary key

Comment: can tell me how solved it because i had the same problem just a week ago and for me i solved it by using another auto generated primary key for room db